# Glassfish not loading secure page

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, glassfish-3

I've made a basic login on my Glassfish server, when I try it the username and password is recognised and accepted but nothing is loaded, the browser seems to attempt to load something but instead just sits on the initial page.

I have made an account in file realm and the login is successfully recognised.

The link which brings up the login is: `<a href="secureUser/secret.xhtml">`

In `web.xml` I have this:

```xml
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>UserConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>User</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/secureUser/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Any ideas as to why it doesn't load `secret.xhtml`?

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, link is: "secureUser/inside.xhtml"

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a security-role-mapping in your sun-web.xml, such like this:

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <principal-name>admin</principal-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

Replace the content of `<principal-name>` with the user name of your file realm.

If this doesn't help: You can change the logging of glassfish's security module. Change the log level of the `javax.enterprise.system.core.security` module to `FINEST` in the admin console.

Hope this helps!